# Even smaller Windows 11 desktop icons

Tags: desktop-customization, windows-11, desktop-icons

Just after installation, desktop icons were quite small, way smaller than on Windows 10, and this suited me well.

Then having once clicked right button on desktop and choosing "View", I accidentally clicked on "Small icons". As a result, the icons became *larger* (sic!), and now I cannot find a way to have back those cute tiny icons.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I cannot find a way to have back those cute tiny icons. Does anyone
> know how to do it?

Windows 11 Desktop Icons can be made any size you wish.

Pick a blank space on your Windows 11 Desktop.

Hold down the Control Key and then roll the Mouse wheel. Desktop icon size will change.

This method of changing the size of Desktop icons works in Windows 11 and also in Windows 10.

Comment: What if you don't have a mouse wheel?

Comment: @Michael most touchpads have pinch to zoom. and, well i'm not on windows but... if you don't have a touchpad either, it's always worth trying good old ctrl minus

Comment: Ctrl-minus doesn't work on my machine (Windows 10 21H1 19043.1348). I do have a mouse wheel which does work though...

Comment: Ctrl Mouseswheel works on Windows 10 bur not Ctrl-Minus (same on Windows 11)

Comment: @Michael Maybe ctrl-downarrow then?

Comment: Crtl- Up Down arrow does not control icon size either. Just Ctrl and mouse wheel.

Answer (score 0):

The number 1 answer works well for changing the size of the icons, but I want to move my icons closer together.  Currently it only allows 6 icons across the top regardless of the size of the icon.

You can also only go about 2/3 of the way down wit any row, and the rows are quite far apart.  Is there a way to change that?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).